# react antd upload component is repeating elements when rendering images after GET from server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

when the component is rendered for the first time, it gets its content from an api call response and shows that. It should show an array of images(which it does), but it is repeating some of them, the component Upload double shows the first n-1 elements in the array `fileListGallery`, even when in the component the array `fileListGallery` does not have repeated values

**here is the most significant part of the code involved**

```
const [images, setimages] = useState({
        previewVisible: false,
        previewImage: "",
        previewTitle: "",
        fileListGallery: [],
        fileListThumbnail: []
    })

const product = useSelector(state => state.product);
const { gallery } = product;
```

this is the state of the component and variables from global state

```
useEffect(() => {
   dispatch(getProductFiles(pid));
},[])
useEffect(() => {
   gallery ? setimages(gallery) : null;
}, [gallery])
```

here I dispatch an action for getting the images from the server and assign the response to the local state, the response from the server is an array of objects(images) which is assigned to `fileListGallery`

```
example object(image)
{
    "id": 187,
    "url": "imageurl",
    "urlBig": null,
    "urlSmall": null,
    "name": "file-20210617012922",
    "mime": "image/jpeg",
    "uid": "__AUTO__1623937098548_0__"
}
```

ant.design upload component returned.

```
const { previewVisible, previewImage, fileListGallery, fileListThumbnail, previewTitle } = images;

return (
<Upload
   listType="picture-card"
   fileList={fileListGallery}
   onPreview={handlePreview}
   onChange={(list) =>
   handleChange(list, { type: "thumbnail" })
   }
   action={`server url`}
   headers={{ 'Authorization': `Bearer ${tokenHelper.getItem('token')}` }}
   onRemove={onRemoveImage}
   accept="image/*"
   >
   fileListGallery.length >= 1 ? null : uploadButton}
</Upload>
)
```

[an example of the repeated images in the Upload component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u58JD.png)